# UI libraries using styled components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I'm guessing not all UI frameworks are easily used together with styled components; since their specificity could be too high etc.

Am I correct in this regard?

Is there any pattern for styled components that allow them to work with any UI framework?

Is there a pattern to frameworks, that allows them to work really well with styled components, while not being written in it?

I know this could be subjective, but I am trying to ask about an objective pattern for interoperability.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I'm guessing not all ui frameworks are easily used together with
>   styled components; since their specificity could be too high etc. Am I
>   correct in this regard?

No, `styled-components` works with any third party component library as long as the components attach the `className` internally to DOM node. See [here](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/6115#issuecomment-279142783) the answer of Max Stoiber (co-creator of `styled-components`) in out of the discussions at GitHub.

There is a [binary-ui](https://github.com/opensource-cards/binary-ui) library, it uses `styled-components` it works with `react` and `react-native` as well.

You can definitely use `styled-components` with a [material-ui](http://www.material-ui.com/) library and I guess with many other, I believe most of UI libraries allow using `className` prop.

Comment: This is the correct answer! (Max here) I just want to mention that specifically `material-ui` (currently) uses inline styles, so you'll have to use `!important` in your code to override their styles. They're working on changing that in the next version, but it's not done yet. (see this blogpost if you're unsure what the difference between inline styles and styled-components is: https://mxstbr.blog/2016/11/inline-styles-vs-css-in-js/)